# How to fix `Class constructor LitElement cannot be invoked without 'new'`?

Tags: typescript, polymer, web-component, parcel, lit-element

I am setting up a new project using lit-element from polymer and the build setup includes the use of parcel. I am also using typescript to write my code.

I started by initializing npm and added all the necessary dependencies:

```
"dependencies": {
  "@polymer/lit-element": "^0.6.5",
  "@webcomponents/webcomponentsjs": "^2.2.1"
},
"devDependencies": {
  "parcel-bundler": "^1.11.0",
  "tslib": "^1.9.3",
  "typescript": "^3.2.2"
}
```

Now when I run the parcel to start with index.html which includes:

```
@webcomponents/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-bundle.js
```

I get an error saying:

```
Class constructor LitElement cannot be invoked without 'new'
```

Based on others suggestion I have tried setting tsconfig target to "es2016" but this does not solve the error.

*my-element.ts*

```
import { 
  LitElement,
  html,
  customElement,
  property 
} from '@polymer/lit-element'

@customElement('ui-text')
export class UiText extends LitElement {
  render() {
    return html`<p>Hi</p>`
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

After struggling with it for a while, it seems parcel (as of v1.12.3) has an issue where it doesn't consider the browserslist unless `index.html` is in the same folder as `packages.json`,`package-lock.json`, and `node_modules`. After I reorganized my source files and added `"browserslist": ["Chrome > 46"]` it started working fine.

Answer (score 2):

At the moment, proposed **custom-elements-es5-adapter.js** does not really "adapt" whatever is produced by parceljs (for Chrome). There's much more on this subject in this issue: https://github.com/Polymer/lit-element/issues/54.
Explicitly stating targeted browsers in package.json will help a lot, here's an example:

```
"browserslist": [
  ">2%",
  "Edge > 14",
  "Firefox > 63",
  "Chrome > 67"
]
```

Afterwards, you can check actually targeted browsers with this statement by running `npx browserslist` - see the syntax and more in https://github.com/browserslist/browserslist

The project structure is not an issue and parceljs will detect `browserslist` regardless of index.html and other source files location.

Unfortunately, in my case, IE11 usage is around horrifying 10%, but I'm planning to drop its support regardless with a friendly fall back message.

Comment: This worked for me with `"parcel-bundler": "^1.12.4"`. TY.

Answer (score 1):

Create file `.browserslistrc`
with:

```
last 1 chrome versions
```

And make sure that parcel cache is clear. I recommend you run parcel with a flag:

```
parcel entryPoint --no-cache
```

[More info](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hxn8QDgnb20).

Answer (score 0):

If I understand Parcel correctly, it will always compile your JS down to es5, in which case you will have to deliver the es5 adapter https://github.com/webcomponents/webcomponentsjs#custom-elements-es5-adapterjs which allows for the code to pretend to run as classes which are required to register an actual custom element with `customElements.define()`.